# nestjs returns 404 not found for 1 routes working fine for others

Tags: nestjs

I am using nestjs to create an API, quite new to it. I created 4 modules and all 4 seem to be working fine.
I created another module name steps but all routes I access in it returns 404 not found.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You either have a typo in your @Controller() decorator in your controller file, or you haven't registered the controller in the newly created module (moduleName.module.ts file). Those were the most common errors for me.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Bruno , my issue was similar , actually i didn't import my file_module in the app.module.ts

Comment: Thanks, I had it imported on 'providers' array because of a copy paste of that module from another personal API built using GraphQL (it was a resolver and those are imported on the 'providers' array)

Answer (score 9):

when after add new routes and controllers, we should clean up `dist` folder and restart `yarn start:dev` to make sure the added fils work...

Answer (score 5):

Run the following commands when you add new routes and controllers.

```
yarn run build
yarn start
```

Answer (score 5):

extending @Bruno's answer for new user. Make sure all your modules are added to import

[image]

Answer (score 4):

perhaps the app uses a global prefix (`app.setGlobalPrefix`) and it is easy to forget about it when checking new endpoints

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the route param contains a hyphen which NestJS (or Express?) doesn't accept but it silently returns 404 Not Found.

Say, we have something like `GET /foo/1`.

This fails because of the hyphen in `:foo-id`

```js
@Controller('foo/:foo-id')
export class FooController {

  @Get('/')
  async foo() {}
}
```

After changing the route param name to `:fooId`, it passes.

```js
@Controller('foo/:fooId')
export class FooController {

  @Get('/')
  async foo() {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Got this trouble using a jwt as a route parameter findByJwt/:jwt with a string "toto" it works, with a jwt nestjs return a 404

Answer (score 1):

Go `app.module.ts` and import module in file example.module.ts

Example:

```
import { AgencyModule } from './modules/agency/agency.module';//NEW

@Module({
    imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot({
            load: [configuration],
            isGlobal: true,
        }),
        SharedModule,
        DatabaseModule,
        AgencyModule, //ADD HERE
       
    ],
    controllers: [AppController],
    providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your new file.module.ts and make sure you have everything ok, actually that was my case trying to fix the same problem.

This is what I have now in picture.module.ts (picture is my case):

```
@Module({
    imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Picture]), ProductsModule],
    controllers: [PicturesController],
    providers: [
      PicturesService,
    ],
  })
export class PicturesModule {}
```

this file I showed to you was empty, and I had everything else fine so I was pretty confused, make sure you check it.

Hope it works!